# Response from spring web service is not formatted

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to develop Web services using Spring boot, Hibernate with database MySql. I am using stored procedure to retrieve the list. The response that i get is not in the form of valid json format.

```
[
    2,
    "7598149597",
    "2019-09-02T05:10:43.000+0000",
    "Digital Marketing",
    "2015002",
    "Rohit",
    "Ramakrishnan",
    "C",
    "2019-09-02T05:10:43.000+0000"
]
```

This is how i get the response it should actually be like

```
 {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Rohit",
    "middle_name": "C",
    "last_name": "Ramakrishnan",
    "employee_id": "2015002",
    "designation": "Digital Marketing",
    "contact_number": "7598149597",
    "create_date": "2019-09-02T05:10:43.000+0000",
    "update_date": "2019-09-02T05:10:43.000+0000"
}
```

The Entity class has toString Method that returns

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", first_name=" + first_name + ", middle_name=" + middle_name + ", last_name=" + last_name + ", employee_id="+ employee_id + ", designation=" + designation + ", contact_number=" + contact_number + ", create_date=" + create_date + ", update_date=" + update_date +"]";

}
```

The repository class looks like this

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDetailsDao {
@Autowired
EntityManager em;

/**
 * Retrieve List
 * @return
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Iterable<EmployeeDetailsSP> getEmployeeList(){
    return em.createStoredProcedureQuery("find_all_employees").getResultList();
}
```

The controller class looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/sp/emloyee")
public class EmployeeDetailControllerSP {
@Autowired
EmployeeDetailsDao employeeDetailsDao;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeDetailControllerSP.class);

/**
 * Retrieve List
 * 
 * @return
 */
@GetMapping("retrieve_list")
public Iterable<EmployeeDetailsSP> retrieveList() {
    log.debug("retrieve_list");
    return employeeDetailsDao.getEmployeeList();
}
```

EmployeeDetailsSP

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_details")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(value = {
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "FindEmployeeList", procedureName = "find_all_employees"),
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "FindEmployeeDetails", procedureName = "find_employee_by_id", parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "emp_id", type = Integer.class) }),
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "CheckDuplicateEmployee", procedureName = "check_duplicate", parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "emp_id", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "emp_count", type = Integer.class) }) })

public class EmployeeDetailsSP {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@NotBlank
private String first_name;

private String middle_name;

@NotBlank
private String last_name;

@NotBlank
private String employee_id;

@NotBlank
private String designation;

@NotBlank
private String contact_number;

@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreatedDate
private Date create_date;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@LastModifiedDate
private Date update_date;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getMiddle_name() {
    return middle_name;
}

public void setMiddle_name(String middle_name) {
    this.middle_name = middle_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getEmployee_id() {
    return employee_id;
}

public void setEmployee_id(String employee_id) {
    this.employee_id = employee_id;
}

public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}

public String getContact_number() {
    return contact_number;
}

public void setContact_number(String contact_number) {
    this.contact_number = contact_number;
}

public Date getCreate_date() {
    return create_date;
}

public void setCreate_date(Date create_date) {
    this.create_date = create_date;
}

public Date getUpdate_date() {
    return update_date;
}

public void setUpdate_date(Date update_date) {
    this.update_date = update_date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", first_name=" + first_name + ", middle_name=" + middle_name + ", last_name=" + last_name + ", employee_id="+ employee_id + ", designation=" + designation + ", contact_number=" + contact_number + ", create_date=" + create_date + ", update_date=" + update_date +"]";

}
```

Comment: (1) Show your `EmployeeDetailsSP` class. (2) Strongly consider using Spring Data instead of inventing your own DAO layer. (3) [Use constructor injection.](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) (4) In REST, it is customary for the "get all" endpoint to simply be mapped to `/sp/employees` without a "retrieve" (implied by `GET`) or "list" (implied by not providing a specific ID as in `/sp/employees/{id}`).

Comment: Your stored procedure doesn't return instances of EmployeeDetailsSP. It returns a list of arrays of objects. You need to map those arrays to objects.